# Get all the indexes that fulfill a condition in a vector

Tags: vector, rust

I would like to know if it is possible to get all the indexes that fulfill a condition in a rust vector datatype. I know the trait operator provides a method to find the first element that does it:

```
let test=vec![1,0,0,1,1];
let index = test.iter().position(|&r| r == 1);
println!("{}",index) //0
```

However, I would be interested in obtaining all the indexes that are equal to 1 in the test vec.

```
let test=vec![1,0,0,1,1];
let indexes =  //Some Code
println!("{:?}",indexes) //0,3,4
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use [`enumerate()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.enumerate):

```rust
let test = vec![1, 0, 0, 1, 1];
let indices = test
    .iter()
    .enumerate()
    .filter(|(_, &r)| r == 1)
    .map(|(index, _)| index)
    .collect::<Vec<_>>();
dbg!(indices); // 0, 3, 4
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=f8e306a68f2f0e1324d17be23b976ef3).

You can also combine `filter()` and `map()`, although I think the former version is cleaner:

```rust
let indices = test
    .iter()
    .enumerate()
    .filter_map(|(index, &r)| if r == 1 { Some(index) } else { None })
    .collect::<Vec<_>>();
```

Or

```rust
let indices = test
    .iter()
    .enumerate()
    .filter_map(|(index, &r)| (r == 1).then(|| index))
    .collect::<Vec<_>>();
```

Comment: You can return the index without a closure using `then_some`:

`test.iter().enumerate().filter_map(|(index, &r)| (r == 1).then_some(index)).collect::<Vec<_>>()`